# Генерация набора букв и цифр

Tags: python

захотел я вот сделать рандомную генерацию букв и цифр для создания ID. А я даже не знаю, как это сделать. Буду рад помощи :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import uuid          
print(uuid.uuid1())
```

---

```
c58555a5-48f2-11ee-88fb-e848b8c84000
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Сгенерить рандомный набор символов и цифр можно так, но нет никакой гарантии, что набор символов не повториться, поэтому советую воспользоваться вариантом @Oopss

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits
from random import shuffle
chars = list(ascii_letters + digits)

shuffle(chars)

print(
    ''.join(chars[:10])
)
# 10 это длина значения которого хотите получить
```